# How Do I Get c# to write quotation marks?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I want c# to write a piece of HPKP code into a text box.

What a piece of apache HKPK code looks like:

```
Header always set Public-Key-Pins "pin-sha256=\"base64+primary==\"; pin-sha256=\"base64+backup==\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains"
```

what i tried doing in c#:

```
apacheTextBox.Text = ("Header always set Public-Key-Pins ") + ("pin-sha256=\"base64+primary==\"; pin-sha256=\"base64+backup==\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains");
```

which results in (entered into a text box but shown in code here for clear viewing):

```
Header always set Public-Key-Pins pin-sha256="base64+primary=="; pin-sha256="base64+backup=="; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains
```

As you can see there are two quotation marks missing between:

```
pin-sha256="base64+primary=="; pin-sha256="base64+backup=="; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains
```

So how do i get c# to write quotation marks?

Comment: Hint: the `\ ` in `\"base64` is also missing

Comment: You've sort of answered it in your question, in that the things that you want to output as `\"` are coming out as `"`.  Your next question will be "how do I output \" - the answer being the same, escape it with another "\".

Comment: make this : `apacheTextBox.Text = =@your string;` 
you don't need to \" in order to output "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\" will escape the quote in c# so it will print the quote as a character. Try this

```
apacheTextBox.Text = ("Header always set Public-Key-Pins ") + ("\"pin-sha256=\"base64+primary==\"; pin-sha256=\"base64+backup==\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains\"");
```

Comment: Np please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like what has been shown, use \". You need an escape character \ before writing quotation mark ".

```
apacheTextBox.Text = ("\"Header always set Public-Key-Pins ") + ("pin-sha256=\"base64+primary==\"; pin-sha256=\"base64+backup==\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains\"");
```

Also, if you need the backslash, use double backslash \. The first one is the escape character, the second one the backslash.

```
apacheTextBox.Text = ("\"Header always set Public-Key-Pins ") + ("pin-sha256=\\\"base64+primary==\\\"; pin-sha256=\\\"base64+backup==\\\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains\\\"");
```

The key here is to understand the escape character backslash .